# flutter firebase order by in a condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

the probleme in my code is whenever i add the orderby my code stops working and the data is not displaying even when i don't get any errors

here's the stream i sued :

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchData(String textEntered) async* {

var _search = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(sharedPreferences!.getString("uid"))
    .collection("inventaire")
    .doc(widget.model!.InventoryID)
    .collection("produits").where('BarCode', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: textEntered).orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)
    .snapshots();

yield* _search;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing now, as there isn't much to go on. But you are probably missing an index for the query.

Check your logs if you get anything like: " The query requires an index."

You can read more about it at:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: no i didn't find anything like that but i guess that my syntax is wrong idk what's the right thing i should type in my code (the code works fine when i remove orderby)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using a StreamController to return a modified stream, that way you could refactor the code into a **listen**:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchData(String textEntered) {
  
  var controller = StreamController<QuerySnapshot>();

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(sharedPreferences!.getString("uid"))
    .collection("inventaire")
    .doc(widget.model!.InventoryID)
    .collection("produits").where('BarCode', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: textEntered).orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)
    .snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot qSnapshot) {
       controller.add(qSnapshot);
   });

return controller.stream;
}
```

Using the **StreamController** could even allow you to map the documents out of the QuerySnapshot returned on the **listen** callback handler and instead returning a list of PODO objects already mapped as opposed to the QuerySnapshot. My two cents.

Comment: i get an error : The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([LastUpdate]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([BarCode])" when an inequality operator is invoked.
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 485 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]'